# MVC serverside validation of single posted object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, modelstate

I'm currently using a single action to handle 2 views which use a separate ViewModel like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(PrivateCustomer p, CorporateCustomer c)
{
  if(Modelstate.IsValid) { ... }
}
```

My viewmodels look like this:

```
public abstract class Customer
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string UserName {get; set;}
  ...
}
public class PrivateCustomer: Customer
{
  ...
}
public class CorporateCustomer: Customer
{
  [Required]
  public new string Name {get; set;}
}
```

This means as much as I can use 1 url/action for both (closely related) viewmodels.
The problem is, though, I accept both viewmodels as parameters to my post action, and model validation will occur for both (even though I'll only use one).

Given that I post a PrivateCustomer, which doesn't require a name, I'll still get validation errors on that property.

I was wondering if there's an elegant way to somehow prevent this from happening, preferably without manually removing the errors from my ModelState.

The best thing would be if only either of the 2 objects would be validated.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This would be difficult to do in the model due to the fact that the POST data is checked before you can modify it on the server side. If you did not want to split your action up, I would suggest dropping the [Required] data annotation in the model and validating in the controller like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(PrivateCustomer p, CorporateCustomer c)
{

     if (c != null)
     {
          if (c.Name == null || c.Name == "")
          {
               ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Name is required.");
          }
     }

     if(Modelstate.IsValid) { ... }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by implementing custom ModelBinders for the types you are passing to the action method. In the model binders you can override BindModel. There you can decide how to build each instance of the model and decide whether to include ModelState errors.  As this is done before you enter the action method, your action method will see ModelState errors only when your logic wants it to.